# Is it possible to hide a column from a user group using SharePoint Framework Extensions?

Tags: sharepoint-framework, fieldcustomizers

Would this be possible using a field customizer? I haven't used SP extensions yet so if anyone has good resources/documentation that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's possible. We will need to hide the column value from a system view. Also stop the same user(user group) from customizing the views, to make sure he isn't able to add the column in other views.

[image]

Se in the above image you can change the column value with *** for a specific user group.

More details here: [field customizer spfx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create the extension, but we had to abandon this project because SPFx field customizers only work on modern pages, and some users still use the classic view.